Does the 2024 Twinned Spell no longer work on spells that don't increase their number of targets when upcast?
I've been playing Sorcerer since 2014 came out, and Twinned Spell was a great option to save on spells slots.

When you cast a spell that targets only one creature and doesn't have a range of self, you can spend a number of sorcery points equal to the spell's level to target a second creature in range with the same spell (1 sorcery point if the spell is a cantrip).
To be eligible, a spell must be incapable of targeting more than one creature at the spell's current level.

With the 2024 rework, Twinned Spell got the following rules:

When you cast a spell, such as Charm Person, that can be cast with a higher-level spell slot to target an additional creature, you can spend 1 Sorcery Point to increase the spell's effective level by 1.

From how the text is now written, a spell, like Elemental Bane, can be twinned, but Geas can no longer be twinned?
In the case of Elemental Bane, you can target one additional creature for each slot level above 4th. So if I cast at 4th-Level and Twinned, would it be the same as casting at 5th level? (It will be considered as if it was cast 1 level higher)
While Geas lets you Up-Cast to increase the Spell time to 1 year/make it permanent. It can no longer be twinned, according to the new 2024 rules.
Is that correct?

Yes, that's correct
Rules do what they say they do and if that Metamagic Option says it can only be used with spells, which can be upcast to increase the number of targets, than that is what you can do with that, nothing more, nothing less, unless your DM rules otherwise, of course.
In the case of using that option on Elemental Bane, it would still be considered as a spell that uses a 4th level spell slot (as that is what you are using to cast), but yes, the effect would basically be the same as casting it at 5th level. Twinned spell is practically giving you the ability to cast those spells as if they were those higher versions, while using Sorcery points instead of your much more valuable high level spell slots.

This raises the question, are there any spells where upcasting has additional effects on top of raising the number of targets?

Looking at the list, upcasting either increases duration, damage, or creature count. Never two of those. Most single-target spells I can see, do not have the upcasting option.
Also, spells that are not up-castable become blacklisted from this metamagic. This update made one of the most used metamagic into a very situational thing.

@FernandoFuentesMartins While the spell selection is vastly reduced, so is the sorcery point cost (1SP instead of as many as the spell level), so it's both more situational and less because using it has such a low cost.
Not every sorcerer will pick it now, but the sorcerers that do pick it will be using it at every opportunity.
